# Why am I seg faulting when trying to use the execve sys call?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm writing some assembly code for IA-32 architecture with Intel syntax using the NASM assembler on 32-bit linux (ubuntu distro).

I'm trying to use the `execve` sys call to execute `/bin/sh` but keep segfaulting. I think I'm following the convention for sys calls:

- `eax` - the sys call number which is 11 on my platform
- `ebx` - the address of the null terminated string "/bin/sh"
- `ecx` - the address of a structure containing the null terminated string and a trailing null
- `edx` - a pointer to a null

I'm not sure why this program isn't working as expected. Verifying with `gdb` I see that all the addresses are loaded as I intended. I suspect it has something to with the way I define the `sh` variable.

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
  mov eax, 0xb
  lea ebx, [sh]
  lea ecx, [sh]
  lea edx, [sh+8]
  int 0x80

section .data
  sh: db "/bin/sh", 0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
```

I'm especially confused about using `ecx`. In the above code I load `ecx` with a pointer to the string, but what I really want is a pointer to an array. An array that contains: a pointer to a string, and a null. I've tried to rewrite this code but am still unsuccessful.

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
  mov eax, 0xb
  mov ebx, sh ; pointer to the string '/bin/sh'

  xor esi, esi
  push esi ; argv[1]
  push ebx ; argv[0]

  lea ecx, [esp] ; a pointer to the array
  lea edx, [esp+4] ; a pointer to a NULL
  int 0x80

section .data
  sh: db "/bin/sh/", 0x00
```

- Why am I getting a segfault error?
- How do I use `execve` to execute `/bin/sh`?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what `ecx` is for. Before doing something hard, make sure you know how to use this syscall in C.

Comment: "ecx - the address of a structure containing the null terminated string and a trailing null" [...] That's wrong, `ecx` just needs to be `NULL`. Your first code snippet works fine if you do `lea ecx, [sh+8]` (note the `+8`). You can simplify even more and just do `mov eax,0xb; lea ebx,[sh]; mov ecx,0; mov edx,0; int 0x80;`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using the stack

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
xor eax, eax
push eax ; add a null onto the stack

; hs/n : 68732f6e
; ib// : 69622f2f
push 0x68732f6e
push 0x69622f2f ; add the string in reverse order

mov ebx, esp ; pointer the null terminated string

push eax ; argv[1]

mov edx, esp ; a pointer to null

push ebx ; argv[0]

mov ecx, esp ; a pointer to the array with address and null

mov al, 0xb ; the sys call number
int 0x80
```

or another way. The difficulty for me was building the array properly and handling the nulls

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    xor eax, eax

    mov ebx, filename ; pointer the null terminated string

    push eax ; argv[1]

    mov edx, esp ; a pointer to null

    push filename ; argv[0]

    mov ecx, esp ; a pointer to the array with address and null

    mov al, 0xb ; the sys call number
    int 0x80

section .data
    filename: db "/bin/sh", 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```